# Angular routung before http answer is received

Tags: angular

I have this page made in Angular. It has a signin page, which will call "login" on an remote API.
The GUI will route back to "signin" before the answer is ever received.

I have added a timeout to the http call, but that is not respected. I cannot see any script time out or any other reason why it should reload in less time than it takes require the login.
When it accidental logs in, and goes to the "main", then it works from there.
The issue seems to be with login -> answer - just times out somewhere.

The code does not catch any errors, just reloads/refreshes/starts all over
Also I do not see the "pong" very often.
The API logs everything, and it works well. I usually responds in less than 3 seconds (I fixed that it used to be worse)

What could be wrong and what should I look at?

```
    signIn(name, pass) {
        const credentials: IAccount = { UserName: name, UserPassword: pass };
        this.loginService.login(credentials).subscribe(
          result => {
            console.log("****** response 1"); // process result, it rarely reaches this point
// in stead of receiving any result, it has refreshed and reloaded the signin page
```

The long module looks like:

```
login(model: IAccount) {
    return this.http.post<IResponse>(this.url, JSON.stringify(model), { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
      timeout(99000),
      tap(result => { alert("pong"); console.log('Login result: ' + JSON.stringify(result)) } ),      
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

Comment: You didn't share with us what you do after in `signIn` method

Comment: Hi Gaël
I process it - basically  if(error==0)   window.location.href = '/main'; else alert(translatedErrorCodeToString);
But, my question is why I never reach this point. Signin -> sends the request to API -> refreshes/reloads without ever getting the answer.

Comment: Please update your question with the full code of `signIn`. It's not clear where you do `window.location.href`: inside the subscribe, or outside?

Comment: Gaël, that does not matter. It could be alert(loginresult). My issue is that I never reach that line. I send the request, the API responds but at that time the GUI is no longer listeting

Comment: For this to happen you should have a interceptor for your http calls or as Gael J said, the method calling signIn is doing something. Do you have http interceptors in your project?

Comment: Felipe, I got this project and I am fixing. There are probably a few surprises for me here. I looked into the idea of interceptors but I cannot see any in the project (it is really not too big)

Comment: @sonnich yes it matters, if you are doing `window.location.href` outside of `subscribe` it will get executed right away and never wait for the call to the API to be finished.

Comment: Gaël - I checked that as the first thing - that is not the case

Comment: Even an alert or console.log as the only line in "subscribe" will hardly get called, about every 4th time or so

Comment: Still, from what you posted there is no way for us to help you

Comment: Also what does `handleError` do?

Comment: Handle error catches the error and currently logs to console and shows it as an alert. I never goes there

Comment: I made it work, and created a new page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67990203/weird-behavior-of-angular-routing
I will delete this one by friday

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue
It is related to refreshing when clicking a button and can be fixed by a simple return false; when the method/function is done

I found this issue described here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8537

The signin component, see last line

```
signIn(name, pass) {
   const credentials: IAccount = { UserName: name, UserPassword: pass };
   this.loginService.login(credentials).subscribe(result => 
   { // async code
      console.log("****** response 1"); 
      if(login.ok) {
        router.go.to(.... routing stuff)
      } else {
        // show error to user 
      }
    } // end of async code
   return false; // THIS line was needed for it not to refresh
}
```