# Weird behavior of Angular routing

Tags: angular

I have asked before about my weird routing problem.
I now have a solution, and still occasionally weird behavior.
My page is supposed to go to "signin", once succeeded then to "main". This actually works now, except is goes to signin-> home -> blank ('') -> home. The last "flash" or refresh I dont understand. This explains the original behavior where it would always default to the "signin" page, hardly ever staying on the home page.
It happens that it does not "flash" (blank and reload/refresh). The console clears at this moment.

Now it works, but I still feel a bit weird about it.

As of now:

1. page opens
2. empty goes to main
3. on "main" it will look into the SiginGuard, which will route it to "signin"
4. signin page opens
5. user enters credentials
6. main page opens
   --- here follows the weird stuff :
7. it goes to empty, to the redirect,
8. then opens the main again by redirect

I have had alert()'s  everywhere to  track it - nothing unexpected happens

*Last note: in case of a login that lasts longer than 4~5 seconds, it will reset to signin page. When signing in again it will go to the main page and not flash (as it "did" that already).
At times the API can be slow. My timeout did not have any affect, something in my http does not wait long enough for this.*

All the code:
The routing:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'signin',
    component: SigninComponent,
    data: {
      title: 'Login',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },
  {
    path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [SigninGuard],
    data: {
      title: 'Main page',
      subtitle: ''
    }
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/main',    /// this used to be /signin - which would just should the signin page forever
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
    data: { title: '404' }
  }
];
```

The SigninGuard:

```
 canActivate() {
    const currentUser = this.loginInfo.getUserName();
    if (!currentUser) {
    //  alert("message for me"); // used to have such alerts to track the code - it did never go here
      this.router.navigate(['/signin']);
    }
  //  another alert here
    return true;
  }
```

The signin component:

```
 signIn(name, pass) {
    console.log("****** initiated");
    const credentials: IAccount = { UserName: name, UserPassword: pass };
      this.loginService.login(credentials).subscribe(result => 
      {
        console.log("****** response 1");
  //       alert("response 1");

        const response = this.getDecodedAccessToken(result.Token.TokenString);
        if(response==null)
        {
          this.loginResult = response.Status;
          alert(this.loginResult); // better error handling needed
          this.router.navigate([ prefix + '/signin']);
        } else {          
          if (response.signum.toLowerCase() === credentials.UserName.toLowerCase()) {
     //       alert("login ok");
            this.loginInfo.setUserName(response.name);
            this.loginInfo.setUserRole(response.role);
            this.loginInfo.setUserId(response.id);

            this.router.navigate([ prefix + '/home']); // goes here - then "flashes"
          }
        }
      },
      error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error; alert("err " + this.errorMessage); }
    );
    console.log("the end");
  }
```

And the loginService:

```
  return this.http.post<IResponse>(this.url, JSON.stringify(model), { headers: this.headers }).pipe(
     // map(sdd => {  return sdd; } ) // used to have an alert to check result here
      timeout(990000000),
    //  tap(result => { alert("pong"); console.log('Login result: ' + JSON.stringify(result)) } ),      
      catchError(this.handleError) // this alerts any error - no errors
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue
It is related to refreshing when clikcing a button and can be fixed by a simple return false; when the method/function is done

I found this issue described here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8537

The signin component, see last line

```
signIn(name, pass) {
    console.log("****** initiated");
    const credentials: IAccount = { UserName: name, UserPassword: pass };
      this.loginService.login(credentials).subscribe(result => 
      {
        console.log("****** response 1");
  //       alert("response 1");

        const response = this.getDecodedAccessToken(result.Token.TokenString);
        if(response==null)
        {
          this.loginResult = response.Status;
          alert(this.loginResult); // better error handling needed
          this.router.navigate([ prefix + '/signin']);
        } else {          
          if (response.signum.toLowerCase() === credentials.UserName.toLowerCase()) {
     //       alert("login ok");
            this.loginInfo.setUserName(response.name);
            this.loginInfo.setUserRole(response.role);
            this.loginInfo.setUserId(response.id);

            this.router.navigate([ prefix + '/home']); // goes here - then "flashes"
          }
        }
      },
      error => { this.errorMessage = <any>error; alert("err " + this.errorMessage); }
    );
    console.log("the end");
    return false; // THIS was needed
  }
```